# nuxt auth calls user before login and gives 401

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I created a NUXT site with the NUXT AUTH and it works fine, except when I enter the first page on the web app. The web app tries to call the user endpoint but since I haven't logged in yet this endpoint naturally returns

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

My nuxt auth configuration in `nuxt.config.js` looks like this

```js
    auth: {
      strategies: {
        local: {
          endpoints: {
            login: {
              url: '/token',
              method: 'post',
              propertyName: 'access_token'
            },
            logout: { url: '/api/account/logout', method: 'post' },
            user: {
              url: '/api/account/getCurrentUser',
              method: 'get',
              propertyName: false
            }
          },
          tokenType: 'bearer',
          autoFetchUser: true
        }
      },
      redirect: {
        home: '/',
        callback: false,
        logout: '/',
        login: '/login'
      }
    }
```

Can anybody help me get rid of the `401` error? I just want the user endpoint to be called after login

Comment: I suspect that the application still thinks there is a active token, and that it tries to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one reason and two scenarios.

1. You forgot to set `auth: false` on the homepage which does not require login and it is trying to get the user with expired token.
2. If the homepage should be behind login, then again the token is probably experied and in this case I suggest to handle all 401 globally with logout.